# Spring-security выводит имя уже авторизованного пользователя в форму для авторизации

Tags: java, tomcat, авторизация, spring-security

Есть сайт с авторизацией spring security с использованием базы данных(по логину и паролю соответственно).controller не использую, все делаю через managed bean. Использую tomcat. Проблема заключается в том, что если авторизоваться на сайте (не делая после этого logout), то когда захожу на страничку login.xhtml с другого компа (браузера), то в форму login автоматически подставляется имя авторизованного пользователя. Как отключить запоминание или автоподставление этих данных. autocomplete="false"("off") пробовал - не помогает

Comment: Наверно пользователь у тебя синглтон.

Comment: Пользователь у меня @Entity

Comment: Создаю через jparepository @ Autowired UserDao userDao;

Comment: Отключить запоминание можно в браузере, какой браузер у тебя?